# MySQL return 1 row from each letter of alphabet not using UNION?

Tags: mysql

I want to return 1 row for each letter in the alphabet.  For example the table below goes from names a to z.  In the production database i have 1000s of names.

```
id| name
1 | amy
2 | anna
3 | barry
4 | blake
5 | baron
6 | charles
```

I want a query to return 1 row for each letter.  I know how to accomplish this with `UNION` but how do i accomplish this in a single query without `UNION`?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'a%' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'b%' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'c%' LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'd%' LIMIT 1
```

I'm expecting results returned:

```
[0]=>amy
[1]=>barry
[2]=>charles
```

Comment: Why barry and not baron?

Comment: I just want 1 row returned if a match exists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by the first character.

```
SELECT name
FROM names
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1);
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8ee2a/2)**

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'amy'),
(2,'anna'),
(3,'barry'),
(4,'blake'),
(5,'baron'),
(6,'charles');


SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP  
           BY LEFT(name,1)
     ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | amy     |
|  3 | barry   |
|  6 | charles |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: I prefer your solution since you take into account the first occurrence of a name. Also the `LEFT` function is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an aggregate and group by perhaps;

```
select * from
(
select max(id) as maxid, substring(name,1,1) as first letter from tablename
group by substring(name,1,1)
) t1
join tablename t on t.id = t1.maxid
```